# How can I see where my orders are coming from?

Tags: order-splitting

I am using m2e to sync my products with ebay and amazon I also have 3 store fronts...

All going well however I can't see where my orders are coming from whether it was ebay or amazon or direct...

How can I access this information? Would be good to see statistics on where all orders are coming from right?

I can't find it on the dashboard, I've had a google and nothing there either!

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The official advise is to setup a store view for each channel, and configure m2e to use that store view. That way, from the order view, you can filter on the store view.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the "Sell on Multi-Channels" menu item?  Sales | Orders from here.